# Pusher trigger() method is giving error 500

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, pusher, pusher-js

So I was building chat functionality in laravel for a website using **Pusher** , everything was working fine till yesterday. But when I run the chat module again, I found out that `trigger()` method is giving error (Internal server error).
`

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Model\Chatting;
use App\Model\Seller;
use App\Model\Shop;
use Brian2694\Toastr\Facades\Toastr;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Events\Message;
use Pusher\Pusher;
class ChattingController extends Controller
{
    public function seller_message_store(Request $request)
  {
    //return 'hello';
    if ($request->message == '') {
        Toastr::warning('Type Something!');
        return response()->json('type something!');
    } else {
        $shop_id = Shop::where('seller_id', auth('seller')->id())->first()->id;

        $message = $request->message;
        $time = now();

        DB::table('chattings')->insert([
            'user_id'        => $request->user_id, //user_id == seller_id
            'seller_id'      => auth('seller')->id(),
            'shop_id'        => $shop_id,
            'message'        => $request->message,
            'sent_by_seller' => 1,
            'seen_by_seller' => 0,
            'created_at'     => now(),
        ]);
    //return auth('seller')->user()->seller_plan_id;
    if(auth('seller')->user()->seller_plan_id>2){
     // pusher
     $options = array(
        'cluster' => 'ap2',
        'useTLS' => false
    );
    $pusher = new Pusher('app auth key','app secret','app_id',$options);
    //return $request->user_id;
    $data = ['from' => auth('seller')->id(), 'to' => $request->user_id,'message'=>$request->message]; // sending from and to user id when pressed enter

    $pusher->trigger('channel-name', 'event', $data);//here is the issue
    }

        return response()->json(['message' => $message, 'time' => $time]);

    }
  }
}
```

`

If I comment out the `trigger` line, it gives no error.
It was working completely fine till yesterday.

Comment: If you are experiencing HTTP errors with the Pusher API then you should contact Pusher Support via https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/requests/new who can help

Comment: Can you please check the exact pusher version in your `composer.json` file.

Comment: `"pusher/pusher-php-server": "5.0"` I have mentioned this in question also. @a_man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version 5.0 of pusher is broken and has given me errors in the past.

What you could do is, change

`"pusher/pusher-php-server": "5.0"`

to

`"pusher/pusher-php-server": "^5.0"`

And then run the command **composer update**